# how do you align a css fixed element within a relative container?

Tags: css

I am trying to position a fixed "Header" inside of a scrollable container...  So that as you scroll, the header is always at the top...  For some bogus unknown reason, it always places the header at the actual top of the window rather than the position: relative container.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/1hzpLupq/2/

Can anyone explain:  1)  Why this happens, and 2) How can I achieve my goal?

Thank you.

```css
.outer-container {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
.offsetinator {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}
.row {
  background: green;
}
.row span {
  background: gray;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="offsetinator">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="row">
            <span>thing1</span>
            <span>thing2</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A position that's fixed will always be relative to your viewport, so that's already going to prevent you from doing what you want it to be.

The only suggestion I can think of is altering the structure of your HTML so that the header is OUTSIDE of the container with the foobars. If it's outside, you can then use absolute or relative and move it using top/left to where you want it to be.

So all I really did to get this to work was that I moved the header outside the container, and gave the header a position of relative. That's all.

http://jsfiddle.net/1hzpLupq/5/

```css
.outer-container {
    height: 1000px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
}

.offsetinator {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background: teal;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    background: green;
}

.row span {
    display: table-cell;
    background: gray;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="offsetinator">
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>thing1</span>
                        <span>thing2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="container">
               
    
                <div class="body">             
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` is always relative to the viewport (your browser window).

I think you can achieve your goal by using `position: absolute` on the `.header` and by moving `height: 50px` and `overflow: auto` from the `.container` to the `.body`. You will need to change the `height` as the header isn't part of it anymore.

```css
.outer-container {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
.offsetinator {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}
.body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
.row {
  background: green;
}
.row span {
  background: gray;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="offsetinator">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="row">
            <span>thing1</span>
            <span>thing2</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>foobar 1</span>
            <span>foobar 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{ 
margin:0;
}

.outer-container {
    height: 1000px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
}

.offsetinator {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background: teal;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;       
    background: orange;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    background: green;
}

.row span {
    display: table-cell;
    background: gray;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="offsetinator">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>thing1</span>
                        <span>thing2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="body">             
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span>foobar 1</span>
                        <span>foobar 2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add into css:
    body{ 
    margin:0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

1. `position: fixed` will always ignore the box model all the way up to the document body.
2. Unfortunately but probably for good reason there is no way to position fixed relative to a parent element(except the body). The solution: remove the fixed styles and add the scrolling to the your `<div class="body">`

   **JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1hzpLupq/6/